# Wrapping 2 vertically stacked divs, 1 div 100% high

Tags: html, css, height, viewport, stacked

I've been strolling around the internet for a while but I can't seem the find a fix for my problem.
Perhaps you could help me out.

## The issue

I am trying to wrap a div around 2 vertically stacked divs. At this moment I have a top div, which is viewport filling (100% height, 100% width) and a bottom div, which is of variable height but with a 100% width.
The top div serves as a container for horizontally and vertically aligned content.

As soon as I apply a wrapper to the two divs, the top one collapses. It stops filling the entire viewport height.

## The example

**The current HTML looks like this:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top_content">Top content</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom content</div>
```

With of course a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4u4nqrcv/

**The HTML I need looks like this:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="top_content">Top content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">Bottom content</div>
</div>
```

Also with a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggsztx78/

*You can clearly see top div collapsed*

## The question

How can I wrap the 2 vertically stacked divs, maintaining the viewport filling height of the top div? I just need to find out exactly what CSS I should apply to the wrapper and possibly the 2 wrapped divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the viewport unit vh. `100vh` = 100% of the viewport height.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggsztx78/3/

```
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f4f;
    display: table;
}
```

Support isn't [that bad](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) if you are not using `vmin` or `vmax`.

Comment: It seems like that did the trick in the JSFiddle. I will test it in my development environment first though.

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work! I will do some more extensive browsertesting but for now I will leave it like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggsztx78/1/)
It's easy, you did not set any css parameter to the wrapper, and it needed to also have height and width of 100%, margin and padding set to 0.

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Is it ok for you to use jquery for this? You can set the wrapper height to have the combined heights of the two inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also give the wrapper a `height: 100%`.

By setting `height: 100%` you tell an element to become 100% of the height of its parent. Therefore you need to give all ancestors of the `#top-content` an height of 100% to make the `#top-content` take up 100% of the screens height.

Comment: (also replied to @Alin) Unfortunately setting 100% height to the wrapper doesn't completely wrap both stacked divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ggsztx78/2/

You can see the gray (#ccc) background doesn't wrap both divs. This was also one of the issues I experienced.

Comment: It indeed doesn't (try adding `overflow: hidden` to the #wrapper to see what happens). If the support for viewport units is good enough for your case (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) you can try giving the `#top` a `height: 100vh` instead of using `height: 100%` on every element.